# Meaning of "zu" in "Austellung zu Karl Valentin"

Tags: translation

What is the meaning of the word "zu" here in this sentence?

> Der Museumsführer zeigt den Touristen die Ausstellung **zu** Karl Valentin.

Comment: _zu_ means _concerning_ or _regarding_.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach, if the OP had understood that the *zu* belongs to the part *Ausstellung zu Karl Valentin*, she might not have asked. I don't know. Therefore I think that your edit is problematic.

Comment: @CarstenS My edit just corrected the typo _Austellung_ to *Aus**s**stellung*

Comment: Right, sorry, my remark should have been addressed at Hubert then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Der Museumsführer zeigt den Touristen die Ausstellung **zu** Karl Valentin.

It's not an exhibition by Karl Valentin but **about** him. The other possible preposition is *über*, but *zu* gives a slight hint this particular exhibition only focuses some aspects of his work.